# How to add Richtext toolbar editing in custom wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to use the wordpress own text formatting used in gutenberg text blocks to format a text field in the backend of a custom plugin. However I don't want to integrate the whole block concept in the plugin. I just want to format text in a textfield (or a div) using the editor toolbar from gutenberg.

I was searching for the right point to hook in. THe "[Formatting API](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/format-api/)" sounded good, but there I can just add button to the toolbar. But I didn't found a hint how to add the toolbar somwhere on the page outside a [block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/block-controls-toolbar-and-sidebar/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tutorial [Building a custom block editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/platform/custom-block-editor/) from the Documentation walks through the process of creating a custom instance of the Block Editor. The concepts & code demonstrated could be used in your plugin to use/access the Formatting API and create a modern, block-based UI for your plugin settings.